# how to pass an argument into a scrapy spider and init it from within python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

i am trying to pass a variable `screen_name` to my spider because this screen_name will change everytime. ( the end goal is to have multiple spiders running with different screen_names)

i initialise like this

```
process.crawl(TwitterSpider(screen_name="realDonaldTrump"))
```

However i get the following error.

> spider = cls(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'screen_name'

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TwitterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "twitter_friends"


    def __init__(self, screen_name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.usernames = []
        self.screen_name = screen_name
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  


    def start_requests(self):

        base_url = "https://mobile.twitter.com"
        urls = [
            base_url + '/{screen_name}/following'.format(screen_name=self.screen_name,
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def closed(self, spider):
        print("spider closed")

    def parse(self, response):
        pass


process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})


process.crawl(TwitterSpider(screen_name="realDonaldTrump"))
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

This is not a question about how to run it from cmd line but only from within python

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the spider class and its arguments to the `crawl` method. Eg:

```py
process.crawl(TwitterSpider, screen_name="realDonaldTrump")
process.start()
```